# Handling Multitouch on iPhone

Tags: ios, opengl-es, input, multi-touch

I am making an iPhone game using OpenGL. I've run into a problem when I started to write the game controls' interface. I have four buttons (Left, Right, Attack, Jump), and I need to be able to press  and  simultaneously. What I need is like a function touchesStationary (there are only touchesBegin, Moved and End). I need a function that returns all the fingers currently on the screen (doesn't matter their current phases), but those functions only return when I start pressing, when I move a finger or when I lift a finger... There are no functions for when a finger stays in place, pressing the button.

I've tried to write a code using touchesBegin, touchesMoved and touchesEnd, but one functions returns a finger list that is in different order than the others, so it screws everything up, and multitouch becomes impossible.

The ideal function would return all the fingers currently on the screen, then I can iterate through all of them, checking if their positions match the position of some button, and then activate that button. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You're basically talking about implementing a significant chunk of touch-based GUI functionality, with all the complexity that brings. You're going to have to implement a small state machine that keeps track of what's going on with each button. For example, a button starts out in its "not pressed" state. If you detect a touch within the button, it transitions to its "pressed" state. When touches move (or end, or get canceled), you check to see if the button still contains a touch. If it doesn't, you transition back to the "not pressed" state. Your game loop can check the state of the button and generate events accordingly (for example, some buttons may need to generate events continuously when depressed, while others generate a single-shot event when they are released).

Comment: But the problem is the part "check to see if the button still contains a touch". How can I do that? I couldn't find any functions for it. I only receive events when touches start, move or end. If the user is holding the button without moving, it won't get noticed. That's what I need, to check whether there IS a touch in a certain position.

Comment: There is a touch inside a button if there was a touch inside a button (detected as a result of a touchesBegan/Moved call) and you have not since received any touchesMoved/Ended/Canceled: calls that indicate that there is not a touch inside the button. You *have* to store one additional value per button (perhaps a Boolean named `isPressed`) so you can query the button about its current state between touch events. By storing the button state, you have a piece of persistent information that doesn't rely on the touch callbacks.

Comment: Yes, I am storing isPressed for every button. But problem arises because of the multitouch functionality. I can't keep track whether some touchesMoved event is the same finger of some touchesBegin event, so, for example, there's no way to know if the user moved his finger across the screen and stopped on a second button without me unpressing the first button - because there was no touchesEnded in this scenario, and there's no way to know if the finger that moved is the same that pressed the first button (so I could unpress it). It's a bit difficult to explain...